# How to show only years in x axis using ggplot

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I want my multiple line chart to show only years (not years and months) on x axis. I tried to format "years" with `"%Y"` but `df2` shows days, months and year.

```
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_minimal())

df <- tibble(
             year = as.character(c(2015, 2016)),
             v1 = c(3,10),
             v2 = c(7,18))

    df$year <- as.Date(df$year, "%Y")
    format(df$year, "%Y")
    #> [1] "2015" "2016"

    df2 <- df %>%
      gather(key = "variable", value = "value", -year)

    ggplot(df2, aes(x = year, y = value)) + 
      geom_line(aes(color = variable, linetype = variable)) + 
      scale_color_manual(values = c("darkred", "steelblue"))
```

Comment: It doesn't work since it doesn't show only the 2 years. It labels x values as 2 years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `lubridate` package.

You can use `scale_x_date`, since your date is Oct in 2015 and 2016, So I shifted dates by 9 months to display both 2015 and 2016 in the graph.

```r
library(lubridate)
df2 <- df %>%
    gather(key = "variable", value = "value", -year) %>%
    mutate(year = year - months(9))

ggplot(df2, aes(x = year, y = value)) + 
    geom_line(aes(color = variable, linetype = variable)) + 
    scale_color_manual(values = c("darkred", "steelblue")) + 
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year",date_labels = "%Y")
```

Another way would be extracting year from the date column as integer, and use `year`(integer) to plot, you also need to specify breaks.

```r
df2 <- df %>%
    gather(key = "variable", value = "value", -year) %>%
    mutate(year = lubridate::year(year))

ggplot(df2, aes(x = year, y = value)) + 
    geom_line(aes(color = variable, linetype = variable)) + 
    scale_color_manual(values = c("darkred", "steelblue")) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2015,2016))
```

Both results in the same graph.

[image]

Comment: I prefer the second answer. If `year` is a character, an integer or double it works even without `lubridate` . All I have to do is use `scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2015,2016))`